# startActivityForResult passing data through to "toActivityResult" using ArrayAdapter

Tags: android, android-intent, android-arrayadapter, android-gallery

I have created a custom list interface. I'm using an array adapter to manage my list view cell's button clicks. One of my buttons opens a dialog that shows the device's gallery and allows them to choose an image.

In my Adapters `getView` method, I have the on click listeners for the buttons. When I choose the image. The `onActivityResult` method in my Activity gets called as it should. But I'm having trouble reading the `intent.putExtras("id", id)` as it is read as `null` in the Activity. 
Here is my method where the `startActivityForResult` is called in my `MainActivityListAdapter`:

```
public void showExtraPicture(String imgStr, final String qid, String qname) {
    ImageButton gallery = (ImageButton) dialog.findViewById(R.id.gallerybtn);
    gallery.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            System.out.println("BIT: Qid: " + qid);
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setType("image/*");
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            Bundle mBundle = new Bundle();
            mBundle.putSerializable("qid", qid);
            intent.putExtras(mBundle);
            ((Activity) QuestionListAdapter.this.context).startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
            dialog.dismiss();
        } // end method onClick
    }); // end setOnClickListener
```

}

I have tried using Bundle `putSerializable` but that isn't working for me. I'm guessing my problem has to do with me calling the data from the ArrayAdapter.

Here is my `onActivityResult` in my `MainActivity`:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Bundle mBun = data.getExtras();
    String qid = "";
    if (mBun != null) {
        qid = (String) mBun.getSerializable("qid");
    }
    if (requestCode == 1) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(
                    selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            String filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();


            Bitmap yourSelectedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath);
            try {
                Bitmap image = getBitmapFromUri(selectedImage);
                String stringRepresention = BitMapToString(image);

                //Save string to DB
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: why not use putString and getString instead of putserializable ?

Comment: I tried both, I just tried `putSerializable` last before creating this question. Both don't work. Any idea?

Comment: Hi Rami, That didn't work either.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Intent supplied to `onActivityResult()` is not the same as the one you used for `startActivityForResult()`; the activity started for the result will use [`setResult(int resultCode, Intent data)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setResult%28int,%20android.content.Intent%29) to set the Intent supplied to your `onActivityResult()` function.

Therefore, any extras you supply on your original intent are only useful when the target activity (an image chooser, in your case) is doing its job -- you will not see those extras in your result (unless the target activity goes out of its way to copy them into the result intent, of course).

What do you need to propagate `qid` for? You didn't include the usage on the receiving side... so I will assume that you need it to know where to put the chosen image in some way.

In that case, you should use the requestCode functionality. Let your app keep track of pending requests with a requestCode->qid mapping. Make sure to use a unique requestCode for every `startActivityForResult()` call. You will get that requestCode back as an argument to `onActivityResult()` -- look it up in your map, and you'll have the related qid. Don't forget to clean up your map when the requests come back.

Possible caveat: you may need to store the mapping persistently on disk, in case your process is killed while the image selector is on top. That situation will likely be rare, but you should make sure to test it and handle it if needed.

Comment: Would you have any sample code that shows how to do the requestCode->qid mapping?

Comment: Nope, but it shouldn't be that hard. I'd use a [SparseArray](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/SparseArray.html). Just take an int to use as index (one that is *not* already in there -- be careful about races!) and put your qid at that position. Then fetch it in your onActivityResult() code.

Comment: Cool, I understand. Thanks

Comment: Good luck, have fun! :)